# Need to count characters in text file

Tags: java

i have to write code that reads a text file and tells me how many lines and characters are in the file. I had it working but then i realized i had to ignore whitespace gaps so i wrote a method to do it. It works fine for one line but if i have more than one line it seems to count any whitespace. Any help would be appreciated

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Inputfile {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("file name:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fn = sc.next();

    int nrl = 0, nChar = 0;// nrl for number of lines
    String line;// get line content variable

    try {
        File fs = new File("C:/" + fn);
        nChar = length_ws(fs);
        FileReader fr;// for reading file

        fr = new FileReader(fs);
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);
        while (lnr.readLine() != null) {
            nrl++;// count number of lines
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "number of lines:" + nrl + "\ntotal number of chars:" + nChar);

        lnr.close();
        fr.close();// close file
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("File not found");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}

public static int length_ws(File f) throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = null;
    fr = new FileReader(f);
    int i;
    i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    do {

        c = fr.read();// read character

        if (c!= ' ') // count character except white space
            i++;
    } while (c != -1);
    return i - 1;// because the is counted even the end of file
}
}
```

Comment: There are many possible problems with your code. You are using `read()` method which reads byte, not char so you are assuming encoding of file that writes character on one byte. It may work with ASCII but if you will use encoding like UTF16 you will get some problems. Also `if (c != ' ')` ignores only spaces, but will include all other characters like tabulator `\t`, line separators `\n` `\r` or punctuation characters. You should simply handle calculating of chars when you are reading lines (use methods from String and Character classes to get and test these characters from line).

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is reading the space but the line feed (since these are char to).

I suggest that you do only read the file once (now it seems that you read it twice).

As char arrives

```
  c = fr.read()
```

you evalute which char it is check out the asci table [ASCII TABLE](http://www.asciitable.com/), you have space,tabs and line feeds (watch out depending on format you can have two chars LF and CR for line feed)

If you have valid char you advance your char counter.
If you have valid char for linefeed you advance your line count.

Hope this help and improves your coding, good luck

Seeing your comment I added this code, its not perfect but a start

```
int LF = 10; // Line feed
    int CR = 13; // Chr retrun
    int SPACE = 32;// Space
    int TAB = 9; // Tab

     FileReader fr = null;
    int numberOfChars = 0;
    int numberOfLines = 0;
    int c = 0;
    try {
        do {

            fr = new FileReader(new File("fileName.txt"));
            c = fr.read();// read character
            if (c > SPACE) { // space (ignoring also other chars 
                numberOfChars++;
            }
            if (c == LF) { // if does not have LF try CR
                numberOfLines++;
            }

        } while (c != -1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (fr != null) {
            try {
                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: No i am still confused on how to fix it

Comment: Refeering to charset, encoding of file i believe that you don't have to worry for know, if you have a strange language probabaly the space and LF CR is always the same.

Comment: Check out the code note how I'm ignoring all char below 32 (they are all "strange" check the ascii table and when i find the LF (line feed) char count a line feed. If LF does not work try with the CR (Carrage return) char. This is not the most perfect code but you got a start. Futhermore, i close the stream ; ) Let me know if you still have problems

Comment: Thanks very much for your help i will try it

Comment: I was still a bit confused so i modified my code  if (c!=' ' && c!='\n' && c!='\r')

Comment: Well thats ok its your code, important that you understand that everthing in your file is a byte (number) and depending on charset a char if asci the char/byte with value 32 is a space (se the ASCII TABLE) and so on... So basically you need to ask your self which chars do I like to count. es. only letters not numbers then your chars are 65-90 (upper case) and 97-122 (lower case), always refeer to the ASCII table link, In my example I was counting everything above 32 (ignoring chars below since they are "strange"), and counting char 10 as the new line char (normaly a file as both 10 and 13)

Comment: I hope you noted that in same loop I was counting both chars and line-feed

Comment: I just want to keep things a bit simple as we are only learning, i appreciate all your help

Comment: Trust me, as soon as you realize that every c you read is number that corrisponds to the ASCII table it gets simple ....and good luck I hope you enjoy it aswell..